# Why the subscriptions inside the ngOninit need not be covered as per the Jasmine test case

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm calling an API subscription function in the ngOnInit(). But as per the test report, it is already covered without writing any uni test related to code block. The function  is display as covered as per the report. Do we actually not need to covere subscriptions in ngOninit as part of unit test in Angular[image]

Comment: `ngOnInit` is called on the first `fixture.detectChanges();` so even though you didn't explicitly call it, the first `fixture.detectChanges();` will call it for you.

Comment: I'm not telling that ngOnint() does not getting called. I'm telling the function which I'm calling from ngOnint is getting covered  by jasmine test case automatically without writing any unit test case for that perticular function. Which means it is auto covering by jasmine. is this some kind of feature of jamsine ?

Comment: No, it's not a feature of `jasmine`. Most likely `this.globalData.myVar` is `false` and therefore the `if` statement is true and `this.testService.testFunc()` is returning an observable and it goes inside of the `subscribe` block.

Comment: How does that prove that the funtion not needed to cover by any test case. I have not written any test case perticular to that function or ngOnInit. So it has to be in the uncovered lines. But it is showing as a covered line

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure.